# Is there any way to get the data in my table view to calculate and keep running total

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

My table view displays Item, Price and Sale price in a table view, once the user types in the information, is there any way to get my table view to keep a running total of the profit made? Currently it displays the profit in the label once i add the data to the table view, but if i add another product it calculates the profit and clears the old value and just replaces it with the new calculation.

Is there any way to get the calculation to:

1. calculate the profit, then when you add another product, calculate that profit and add on to the old profit calculation. So if the user enters 5 different items it calculates all 5 and shows the total profit for all of the items added, instead of it just clearing the old data and replacing it with the new profit.

1.Save even when you close out the app

```
import UIKit
import SafariServices

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ProfitsLabel: RoundedLabel2!
    @IBOutlet weak var itemTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pricesTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var salepriceTextField: UITextField!

    var items: [ItemRow] = []

    struct ItemRow: Codable{
        var first: String
        var second: String
        var third: String
        }

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            load()
        }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
         return true
     }

    func save(){
        if let data = try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(items) {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "SavedItems")
        }
    }

    func load(){
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        if let data = defaults.data(forKey: "SavedItems") {
            items = try! PropertyListDecoder().decode([ItemRow].self, from: data)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        insertNewItems()
        save()
    }

        func insertNewItems() {
           let newVideoRow = ItemRow(first: itemTextField.text!, second: pricesTextField.text!, third: salepriceTextField.text!)
           items.append(newVideoRow)
           let indexPath = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)
           tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
           let priceValue = Double(pricesTextField.text!)
           let saleValue = Double(salepriceTextField.text!)
           if priceValue != nil && saleValue != nil {
               let outputValue = Double (saleValue! - priceValue!)
               ProfitsLabel.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", outputValue) as String
           }
            itemTextField.text = ""
            pricesTextField.text = ""
            salepriceTextField.text = ""
            view.endEditing(true)
        }
    }   

    extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate{

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return items.count
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
             let ItemTitle = items[indexPath.row]
             let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell") as! ItemCell
             cell.itemLabel.text = ItemTitle.first
             cell.priceLabel.text = ItemTitle.second
             cell.saleLabel.text = ItemTitle.third
             tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0, green:0, blue:0, alpha:1.0)
             cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
             return cell
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
            return true
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if editingStyle == .delete {
                items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
                tableView.endUpdates()
                save()
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use more meaningful names in your struct, use `Double` for the prices and add a computed property to calculate the profit. The CodingKeys are needed to prevent `profit` from being en-/decoded.

```
struct ItemRow: Codable {
    var item: String
    var price: Double
    var salePrice: Double

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {case item, price, salePrice}

    var profit : Double {
       return salePrice - price
    }
}
```

Replace `insertNewItems` with

```
func insertNewItems() {

    let price = Double(pricesTextField.text!) ?? 0.0
    let salePrice = Double(salepriceTextField.text!) ?? 0.0

    let newVideoRow = ItemRow(item: itemTextField.text!, price: price, salePrice: salePrice)
    items.append(newVideoRow)
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

    updateProfitLabel()
    itemTextField.text = ""
    pricesTextField.text = ""
    salepriceTextField.text = ""
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Add a `updateProfitLabel` method to get all `profit` values and sum them up

```
func updateProfitLabel() {
   let profitTotal = items.map{$0.profit}.reduce(0.0, +)
   ProfitsLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", profitTotal)
}
```

call it also in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   load()
   updateProfitLabel()
}
```

You can leave load and save unchanged as the profit is calculated on-the-fly.

Finally – as already mentioned in one of your previous questions and not related to the question – delete `beginUpdates/endUpdates`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if editingStyle == .delete {
         items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
         tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
         save()
     }
 }
```

Comment: i get this error "Cannot assign value of type 'Double' to type 'String?' " at (cell.priceLabel.text = ItemTitle.price) and (cell.saleLabel.text = ItemTitle.salePrice)

Comment: Do the same as in `updateProfitLabel`: `cell.priceLabel.text = String(format: "%.2f", ItemTitle.price)`

Comment: do i delete everything in cellForRowAt? and replace it with that?

Comment: Only the Double values price and salePrice. Please look at the types and try to understand how to convert them.

Comment: Thank you, but it wont run, i get the error " Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "item", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_PlistKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"item\", intValue: nil) (\"item\").", underlyingError: nil)). " in the load() function

Comment: Please delete the saved PropertyList in UserDefaults and start from scratch. Or revert the names of the struct members to your *first, second, third*

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to consider how you structure your data, since you are using UserDefaults, you can create a default to hold all of your added items, that should be updated when you add an item, so instead of creating new instance that runs the profit, you should use a container that keep the data alive until you clear it, like UserDefaults or any other persistence types available.

I modified the code slightly to show you the idea, but the logic is different to show you how you might implement it.

```
   var defaults = UserDefaults.standard

func runTotal(newItemPrice: Double) { 

    defaults.set((defaults.value(forKey: "sum") as! Double + newItemPrice), forKey: "sum")

    print(defaults.value(forKey: "sum"))
}

func insertNewItems() {

            let newVideoRow = ItemRow(first: itemTextField.text!, second: pricesTextField.text!, third: salepriceTextField.text!)
            items.append(newVideoRow)

            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: items.count - 1, section: 0)
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)

            let priceValue = Double(pricesTextField.text!)
            let saleValue = Double(salepriceTextField.text!)

           if priceValue != nil && saleValue != nil {

              // let outputValue = Double (saleValue! - priceValue!)

              runTotal(newItemPrice: Double)
               ProfitsLabel.text = NSString(format: "%.2f", defaults.value(forKey: "sum")) as String
           }
```

Comment: so i would have to change my save() and load() function to do this right?

Comment: You can keep them the same but think about the relation between insertNewItems() and save() and load() which variable those functions have access to to update with your computed calculations. Try to test it and check the results.

Comment: how would i check the results

Comment: Update your code with the new implementation, then run the code on your simulator, check if you getting the correct result with your new implementation. If it works correctly and updates then you are in a good shape.

Comment: it doesnt run, i get three errors, " Argument type 'Any?' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg' ", " Argument type 'Any?' does not conform to expected type 'CVarArg' ", " Expression implicitly coerced from 'Any?' to 'Any' "